# I thought there is a memory intrusion problem, is that right?

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

As below, my code is:

```
int     *text(char *str)
{
    int     *cond;
    int     *temp;
    int     cond_size;
    int     num;
    int     i;

    cond_size = -1;
    cond = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);
    *cond = 0;
    while (*str != '\0')
    {
        if (*str == ' ')
            str++;
        num = 0;
        while (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9')
            num = num * 10 + *(str++) - '0';
        temp = cond;
        cond = malloc(sizeof(int) * (++cond_size));
        i = -1;
        while (++i < cond_size)
            cond[i] = temp[i];
        cond[i] = num;
        free(temp);
    }
    g_size = (i + 1) / 4;
    return (cond);
}
```

And my main function is:

```
int     *text(char *str);

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     g_size = 0;

int     main(void)
{
    int     *test;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    test = text(" 4 3 2 1 1 2 2 2 4 3 2 1 1 2 2 2");
    while(i < g_size)
    {
        printf("\n%d\n", test[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

With the input string `4 3 2 1 1 2 2 2 4 3 2 1 ...`, the following output is printed:

```
==============
|  4 3 2 1   |
|4        '1'| <==
|3         2 |  
|2         2 |
|1         2 |
|  1 2 2 2   |
==============
```

However, as I checked (<==),

'1' was printed as **'4'**,

and it is not correct as I expected.

Is there any memory intrusion in my code when using malloc or another mistake?

Comment: There a few weird things in your code: for example, why do you have the `*cond = 0` line right after storing the address of the heap-region malloc allocated? The first malloc'd memory will be lost. Also you may want to consider checking the retun values of malloc and use [realloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) instead of doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see some problems:

- cond_size is -1:

  ```
  cond_size = -1; // Here is problem
  cond = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);
  *cond = 0;
  while (*str != '\0')
  {
      if (*str == ' ')
          str++;
      num = 0;
      while (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9')
         num = num * 10 + *(str++) - '0';
      temp = cond;
      cond = malloc(sizeof(int) * (++cond_size)); // you are trying allocate memory with size 0
      i = -1;
      while (++i < cond_size)
          cond[i] = temp[i];
      cond[i] = num; // you are writing to not allocated memory
  ```

  You can find more about [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).
- temp is out of range:

  ```
  temp = cond;
  cond = malloc(sizeof(int) * (++cond_size));
  i = -1;
  while (++i < cond_size)
      cond[i] = temp[i]; // temp size is cond_size-1
  ```

  So you should limit loop by cond_size-1.

Please take a look at [fixed version.](https://onlinegdb.com/SJADLQEM8)

```html
<script src="//onlinegdb.com/embed/js/SJADLQEM8?theme=dark"></script>
```

Comment: @stonesteel I hope that I have helped you.